# Relation between signatures of path and signature of Fourier Transform of the path.

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, soft-question, stochastic-differential-equations, rough-path-theory

I am looking for reference or insight to know if there is any work that has been done to compare the signatures of a path and the signature of the Fourier transform of the path. The definition of signature and path refers to rough path theory. Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_path

It may be possible to derive from the definition itself but I need help even if it is so.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Here a document around the subject: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00370570/document&ved=2ahUKEwjc8bCz98DjAhWsDmMBHee_BIoQFjAMegQIBhAL&usg=AOvVaw2GGaVcvHMlH92B1Qki5SEV

Comment: @Zbigniew thanks